# How to call a paint class from another .jar file

Tags: java, eclipse, paint

I have made a `.jar` file in Eclipse to call a paint class. When I finish it gives me an error:

```
JAR export finished with warnings. See details for additional information.
  Exported with compile warnings: Graphics/src/G1.java
  Jar export finished with problems. See details for additional information.
    Could not find main method from given launch configuration.
```

Here is my code to call the paint method:

```
public class G1Starter {
   public void main(String[] args)
   {
       Graphics1 g1 = new Graphics1();
       g1.repaint();
   }
}
```

I tried making a `main` method in the `Graphics1` class but it did not work.

Answer (score 3):

Add the `static` keyword so that the application has a valid entry point

```
public static void main(String[] args)
```

Answer (score 0):

Method 'main' should be 'static'

```
public static void main(String[] args)
```